# Calling a subclass method for a superclass constructor

Tags: java

I have a superclass `Class` and a subclass `SubClass`. Our teacher has asked us to put all the class dependent methods in `Class` and all the independent ones in `SubClass`. For example, I need to have the search and sort methods in `SubClass`.

However, in main, the array list that I work with is defined with the `Class` constructor and it does not let me call the method from the `SubClass` to search/sort.

How can I fix that?

Keep in mind that search and sort need to be in the subclass. I cannot put them in the super class just so the program would work.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post all relevant code.

Comment: I got a lot of code. I tried to siplify it specifically to my problem. Plus if I post the code it appears as a match when I submit it and I get a 0.

pass what as a parameter to whom?

Comment: If you need the `SubClass` methods, why are you using `Class` for your array list?

Answer (score 2):

Don't. That's a terrible idea. Because the sub-class hasn't been instantiated when you're in the `super` constructor. Instead, you have to finish the construction of your instance(s). Then you can call the method with your variable reference.

Answer (score 0):

For just solving problem at hand. You can call the superclass constructor in subclass and instantiate a subclass object. This will let you instantiate the subclass object on which further you can call your sort etc.

```
public class SuperClass {
   //definition
}
public class SubClass extends SuperClass { 
  SubClass(//arg) { 
    super(//arg) 
  }
}
```